# OnClickListener not working in debug mode

Tags: android, debugging, onclicklistener

I'm trying to debug my program  in eclipse. On start the program shows a rectangle and a button. In debug the rectangle and button are shown but when I click the button the debugger never goes inside the on click listener. Here is my code in `MainActivity`:

```
final OnClickListener OnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {             
            case R.id.button3:
                System.out.print("Start pressed");
                new Thread.execute(//some input in class);

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `System.out.print("Start pressed");` OMG ! Use `android.util.Log` ! Thanks a bunch !

Comment: Please tell me how should I use it. I'm new to it. How should I see the result of system.out.print

Comment: show more code for your button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.print("Start pressed");
        new Thread.execute(//some input in class);
    }  
});
```

The `switch` statement isn't needed as the `onClick` is assigned to the `button3`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `OnClickListener` to the **Button**.

```
Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {             
            case R.id.button3:
                System.out.print("Start pressed");
                new Thread.execute(//some input in class);
        }
    }  
});
```